# What is the best way to use connection in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Previously I used **HibernateTemplate**(spring 3) which handles opening connection and closing automatically.
But from spring 4 onward **HibernateTemplate** is depricated. currently I am using **HibernateUtil** as:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

and in **main** access as:

```
Session s1 = HibernateUtil.getSession();

Transaction tx = s1.beginTransaction();
s1.save(er);

tx.commit();
s1.close();
```

this is a simple dummy.

Is this the right way to use it or any better substitute is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Repository
public class CarDaoImpl implements CarDao {

    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Car> getCars() throws DataAccessException {
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select c from Car c");
        List<Car> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
    @Transactional
    public Car getCar(Long carId) throws DataAccessException {
        return getEntityManager().find(Car.class, carId);
    }
```

Please Refer to https://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring a better way is not to manage transactions manually at all and use declarative transaction management so that Spring will do it for you by using its own transaction manager: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html